# Iterating through first groupby level to get second level dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have grouped a dataframe by two columns, user and month, and then used mean() to get the mean of a 'score' value for each month.  What I would like to do now is to iterate through the group by user, and be able to get the month and mean score for each month, so that I can plot them using matplotlib.  The problem is, when I iterate through the group, I am going over ever single month for each user instead of being able to just iterate through the first (user) group.  Please let me know how this is possible, thanks.

Here's what I have so far:

```
user_group = past_year.groupby(['User','month'])['Score'].mean()
for group in user_group:
    #I want to be able to access all months and mean scores for the current user here
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you're trying to do correctly, using multi-hierarchical index like this could work - but it's clunky:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({"User" : ["User1", "User1", "User1", "User1", "User1", "User1"], "Month" : ["Jan", "Jan", "Jan", "Feb", "Feb", "Feb"], "Score" : [5,10,30,30,30,40]})

users = df.User.unique()
months = df.Month.unique()

df =df.set_index(["User", "Month"])

for i in users:
    for x in months:
        print(df.loc[i].loc[x].Score.mean())
```

Then change the print statement depending on what you want to do with the end result.